# UIImageView height on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus Zoomed display mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have a `UIImageView *backgroundImageView` in my ViewController and call in my viewDidLoad

```
[self.backgroundImageView sizeToFit]
```

I found that on the **iPhone 6** the height changes from `667 (Normal display)` to `558 (Zoomed display)`

However on the **iPhone 6 Plus** the height remains the same at `736` for both.

Is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try it. Here Given code based on your current screen height.

```
float img = frame.size.height / frame.size.width;

frame.size.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

frame.size.height = frame.size.width * img ;
```